# How do you add a custom kustomize transformer?

Tags: kubectl, kustomize

I'd like to add a transformer to my kustomize setup, one that includes a dynamic value for the case where the local tag needs to override the production tag.  If there's a simpler and better way to do this that would be great.  I've looked through the [list](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubectl/blob/master/docs/book/pages/reference/kustomize.md) of transformers and generators to see if there was a way to provide this value at runtime (though I think specifically kustomize is designed to never use runtime values).

I can specify something like this:

```yaml
images:
  - name: my-image
    newTag: my-sha1
```

The problem is to change the `my-sha1` value after each new local build to then pick that image when I go to apply the local deployment.

How can I set `newTag` after I run a build locally to match a tag for the image I made locally?  I can easily obtain the latest build tag and provide with to `kubectl apply -f`, but I'm not seeing a flag or environment variable, or something to do so.

Comment: Well just found this and maybe it's the "best" way to do it: https://github.com/kubernetes/kubectl/blob/master/docs/book/pages/app_management/container_images.md#setting-a-tag-from-the-latest-commit-sha

Comment: Well hell, running `kustomize edit` winds up removing my comments in the yaml file...ugh.

Comment: Hello, I'd reckon the way you've described should be okay (apart from removing comment). Also, have you seen this docs by any chance: https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kustomize/tree/master/examples/transformerconfigs/images ?

Comment: Does the above github reference answer the question?